# git push to origin error git-http-push died of signal 11

Tags: git, version-control

I am trying to push my local (master) changes to the repository (origin) but I keep getting a weird error which I do not understand **"git-http-push died of signal 11"**. What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using gitweb, the problem may be in how you're accessing the repository.  In gitweb, the repos are typically stored in /repos.

If you clone using:

```
git clone http://user@server/repos/myrepo.git
```

The clone will succeed, but when you push to this repo, you'll get the error *git-http-push died of signal 11*

The solution that worked for me was to remove 'repos' from the URL:

```
git clone http://user@server/myrepo.git
```

After removing /repos, both clone and push worked correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure you are pushing to a branch that exists, and that you have pulled down the latest code before pushing to master.

Comment: I am pushing to a branch that exists and I have pulled down the latest code before pushing (Already up-to-date). I still get the error.

Comment: Is pushing to a non-existent branch, or to one that can't be fast-forwarded actually correlated with this error message?

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this problem by running `uninstall.sh` and then downgrading to `git-1.7.5.4-x86_64-leopard.dmg` (I had the problem on `git-1.7.10.1-intel-universal-snow-leopard.dmg`).

There's remarkably little useful practical advice on this error (and a lot of frustrated users), so my advice is to switch to an alternative version of git that does not suffer from this problem.

Can you post the version of git you are using?  Is suspect that git-http-push fails on certain versions of git.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same prob. My fix: in my Git Repo Provider settings, there was a checkbox stating

> Git Smart HTTP

Worked after activation. Maybe you can find something similar in your providers settings.